# evaluating "()" in node.js causes wierd behaviour, but browser says syntax error (bug in node.js?)

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I evaluate the expression "()" in node.js (without the quotes), it corrupts the environment. The global object is trashed and nothing works. When i evaluate the same express in the browser console it reports a syntax error. From my research it appears the browser is correct. Is this a bug in the node.js expression parser? Can anyone explain what is happening under the hood? 
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeFcD.png)

Comment: What is it that you expect `()` to mean? Parentheses make sense in many context, but a simple empty pair of parentheses is not a valid expression.

Comment: Also the REPL is the REPL. Try saving `()` into a file and running that with node. You'll get an error.

Comment: It would appear that you are specifically trying to evaluate the invalid expression in the nodejs REPL. You should expect that the REPL has a different set of parsing directives than the standard execution environment

Comment: do you have a file with just `()` in it? because, yes, it's an error, but I don't get what you get

Comment: For what it's worth. You can get out of the "nothing works" mode in node REPL by typing ctrl-c. In truth it's not that nothing works but node is waiting for the code to be complete (by "complete" node means "no longer invalid"). Any code that cannot ever be made to be valid will cause node to get stuck in this "wait" mode. But you can abort by typing ctrl-c

Comment: Whenever you think there's a bug in [insert framework name], it's always not the framework's fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` by itself isn't valid JavaScript syntax.

When Node encounters a Syntax Error in the REPL it waits for more input. It tries to indicate this by changing your prompt to three dots.

This is useful because sometimes you want to enter some code that contains a new line:

```
> () => { // this isn't valid syntax by itself
... }     // but you can complete a valid expression like this
```

In this case there is no input you could add to complete a valid expression, but you can exit the "waiting for input" mode with <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>.

Comment: Related: TIL an arrow function expression can't have a newline before the `=>`.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you're writing your own JavaScript REPL. You know JavaScript's grammar in and out, and you want to abort processing of an invalid input as soon as possible (but NOT before that). So, you decide to read character by character, build token by token and abort as soon as you encounter the impossible token (for a current state, state defined by input processed thus far).

So, you know if users enters `(}`, it's pretty safe to abort - there's no way something meaningful is going to come out of that!

Also, if user enters `(2`, you don't want to abort yet - there are a plenty of valid characters to follow, like `)`, `*`, `,`, etc.

You also know what to expect after `()`. If it isn't `=>...` (lambda expression), than it's invalid token.

Now back to reality. REPL implementations in Node.js, Chrome, Firefox, etc. differ because they can. Some are "smarter" than other, and will abort sooner than others, but that's really up to them.

Node.js chose to have "less smart" REPL, as it won't abort reading your input, as soon as it can. In fact, if you entered something that can never form a valid expression, it will leave you hanging, reading junk until you explicitly abort with `Ctrl+C`.

Chrome's console is a little bit smarter. When you type `()`, you'll get:

```
> ()
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

but, when you start typing a lambda `()=>`, it will allow you to finish it in the next line:

```
> ()=>
2
```

As a comfort note, you'll get the same error in Node.js REPL if you indicate you're done with entering of your expression, like this:

```
> eval("()")
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just what happens when Node can't parse the expression you have typed, and it's waiting for more input to see if it can complete the parse. Try any other nonsense like `(((` `)`, etc. and you will get the same result. You can use `Ctrl-C` to abort the parse and get back to a working prompt.